# Radio Streaming - TuneIn example

Tags: android, streaming, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create a very simple app like TuneIn with just one radio station for example.

I have tried to stream the url from VLC, but VLC tranforms to mms and then it streams it.

Can you please provide some guidelines or hints how TuneIn works, protocol that is uses, etc, or even how Android supports streaming radio?

Apologize for this quite vague question, but I haven't found anything well-documented on this specific matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could draw inspiration by browsing the code of NPR Radio - a freely available open-source app: http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/

Comment: Thanks I will have a look and come back! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option you have is to use the FFmpeg library in your app. FFmpeg will be able to connect to mms streams and decoded the relevant audio codec. This is probably the way how TuneIn works too.